# How to read RDF reports files

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I have over 500 RDF reports files and i need to collect all them in 1 folder, read and find some code. I need to find out if the report contains a certain code. Each report has its own ID, after which I have to get which report contains a specific code

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you installed **Oracle Reports Builder** (or Developer, depending on version), you'd be able to *open* those reports and easily see what they are doing.

Without it, as RDF files aren't actually text files, you *can* open them in any **text editor** (such as Notepad) and use its search capabilities to find what you want. That's most probably a `SELECT` statement.

How does it look like? Ugly; have a look at RDF excerpt (`select` begins at line #7):

```
>   0 ˙˙˙˙ Ć0808¨ Ä  ®   ®function IME_REPORTAValidTrigger return boolean is
    report varchar2(40);
begin
    srw.get_report_name(report);
    :IME_REPORTA:='Report: '||report;
  return (TRUE);
end;˙˙˙˙˙˙ Ë0808¨ É  ł   ł  SELECT id_asl,
         app_user,
         naziv
    FROM adresa_slanja
   WHERE id_asl = :par_id_asl"˙˙˙˙ É€6€J€R€b|(‚ †€Šŕ•(ž€˘ŕ­(¶€ş€ş(ş(ľ(ÂpĆpĆpĆpĆpĆĆ Ç  SQL*ReportWriter  REPORT  ERVÍše adresa_slanja TÚ    @ "   ERVxv)
  ¤ !  ERVxv
     ¤ !      5   @ 100g0b88 ˙˙ ŕŕ ˙˙˙˙ (00x"# $ &˙˙
```

If you had **JSP** files instead (or along with RDFs), that would look prettier as JSPs are easily readable in a text editor.

---

However: as you said

> I have to get which report contains a specific code

why wouldn't you just search through all those reports from your operating system? There are various tools that let you **search through files** (i.e. not only by their names, but their contents as well).

I use [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) (which is free for personal and commercial use): specify which files you want to search through (*.RDF), specify what you're looking for (e.g. "from adresa_slanja") and it'll return all files that contain that string.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently resolved this for myself. What I ended up doing to resolve the issue is: I created a python script which uses `rwconverter` to convert all reports to `XML`, from there I used regex to look for the line and then replace it.
After that I used `rwconverter` to convert it back to `RDF` and that's it.

Beware: If you had problems with fonts, those fonts will disappear from reports.